# Listbox scroll is slow with scroll wheel

Tags: c#, performance, listbox, scroll

I've got a ListBox with a few thousand entries ( strings ) and scrolling with the mouse wheel is a bit slow, while scrolling with the scroll bar is very fast.
When I rotate the mouse wheel, the list starts scrolling very slowly for about a second, then it's fast. If I rotate again, it happens again. If I scroll for a longer time ( a few seconds ), the ListBox "memorizes" the instructions and keeps scrolling for another few seconds after I stop rotating the wheel.

Comment: Fast or slow, scrolling through a list with thousands of entries will never be a fun or easy task.  I hope you at least include a search box or filtering mechanism.

Comment: Quacks like a mouse driver 'enhancement'.  Try it on another machine.

Comment: It's probably not a rendering issue with the standard ListBox. I just added 100,000 long string entries to a ListBox on a laptop, and the mouse wheel worked just fine. Not a definitive test by far, but I'm pretty sure you've got something else going on there (handlers, background threads, resource issues, etc...).

Comment: What method are you using to fill the items? Do you set the DataSource or do you add items through Items property of the ListBox copntrol? Try switching the method, might help...

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the records into intervals of 100. You can modify the event OnScroll and check the bounds and see if it's towards the bottom of the list, then you can load the next 100 and so forth. The same goes for when you go towards the top.

It's kind of ghetto, but IMHO I think it'll be more efficient. Plus it'll require more logic.

You may need a beefier system for this.

Comment: Unfortunately the vertical scrollbar won't ever show how many items the listbox contains. I mean, when you load all items at once you can see how long the list is by the size of the vertical scrollbar.